# List of certificate authorities in browsers and mobile platforms

Tags: certificate-authority

Is there a list of certificate authorities installed in popular browsers and mobile platforms?

I am considering a few alternatives for an SSL certificate, and I would like to make sure that the one that I'm buying is covered by all relevant platforms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is, but each browser may use a different set, here is a list for the main browsers:

- Firefox: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/included/
- Chrome: it uses the certificates [included with the OS](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy).
- Opera: it install the most uses CA within installing the application, you can find the rest in the online root repository: https://certs.opera.com/
- iOs: https://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012

Comment: Any idea about mobile platforms?

Comment: Here you have a list for iOS http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012 they are easy to find using the following keywords: "root cert list" "CA list"...