# Add certificate authority to one browser only

Tags: tls, windows, web-browser, certificate-authority

For testing purposes, I'd like to add a "CA" to the list of trusted-CA's of one browser - and use it only for testing. I want to make sure that it won't get added to the computer's trusted CA list.

So - Will adding it to the browser's trusted-CA's really be just that? Or will it be automatically added to the **computer**'s trusted-CA's list?

Comment: There is a detailed explanation of how to do this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650751.aspx (be advised following the bare bones methodology would enable you to do the same on a Unix based machine)

Comment: @munkeyoto Thanks. But what's mentioned there seems to be exactly what I'm trying to avoid. - from that page: `Install Your Client Root Certificate Authority on the ... Machines`

Comment: You can remove it right after. For something like you described, I would follow what is on that page while in a virtualized environment for added security measures

Comment: I've now found [this answer on this site](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/49008/12012) saying that Firefox does indeed have a separate list. That implies that it would be fine if installing on Firefox. (As mentioned in an answer here.) I would, still, prefer a confirmation that FF won't add it to the computer's list, if such a source exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that install Firefox. Firefox comes with its own trusted CA store and what you add there will only be available to Firefox.

Comment: No, common knowledge. You will also see different dialogs with Firefox CA store.