# Official trusted certificated entities

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I am learning about root certificates entities and I have a few questions about that. As far as I know my browser trust in a root certificates entities and I can find the list in "configuration" > "manage certificates" > "etc":

[image: trusted certificates]

Can I contrast this list with an official list? I found [this](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/data/ssl/certificate_transparency/log_list.json) about Chrome trusted certificates entities but for example business like Simantec or Let's Encrypt dont appear and are certificates trusted by my browser. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is not a list of trusted root CAs, but a list of trusted [Certificate Transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/) logs.

Actual lists of CAs for browsers can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49006/list-of-certificate-authorities-in-browsers-and-mobile-platforms). Note that chrome does not have its own list, but uses Windows root certificate store.

Answer (score 1):

For reference read through the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) for a certificate authority.

**To Answer the question**

The short answer is that there is no official list of certificate authorities because technically, anyone can be certificate authority. Your best "list" is look through the top providers or follow a companies list such as Microsoft.

**Third Party Certificate Authorities**

A company such as Microsoft pre-defines Trusted CA's based on their [Microsoft Trusted Root Certificate Program](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx). If you pass you can get your Root CA defined as Trusted and distributed across their products.

Most companies which provide large scale public clients have a program to define trusted CA's.

**Internal Certificate Authorities**

These are certificate authorities which are usually created by your company. They allow for the creation, management, and revocation of certificate which are controlled and Identified from you/your company. While there is a Grey-Line here because many of the Third Party Trusted Certificate Authorities have managed services which help companies run internal certificate programs, they are not required.

Companies will use GPO's to distribute their internal CA Certificates to all devices so that users feel like there is seamless trust across the organizations, however, a client that doesn't have the CA Certificate will not trust the issued certificate without having the CA Certificate loaded on their system.